# scala newbie having troubles with Option, what's the equivalent of the ternary operator

Tags: scala, scala-option

I've already read that the if statement in scala always returns an expression

So I'm trying to do the following (pseudo code)

```
sql = "select * from xx" + iif(order.isDefined, "order by " order.get, "")
```

I'm trying with

```
val sql: String = "select * from xx" + if (order.isDefined) {" order by " + order.get} else {""}
```

But I get this error:

```
illegal start of simple expression
```

order is an Option[String]

I just want to have an optional parameter to a method, and if that parameter (in this case order) is not passed then just skip it

what would be the most idiomatic way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

-- edit --

I guess I hurried up too much to ask

I found this way,

```
val orderBy = order.map( " order by " + _ ).getOrElse("")
```

Is this the right way to do it?

I thought map was meant for other purposes...

Comment: The reason your code isn't compiling is because you need parentheses around the `if` expression. But as Tomasz Nurkiewicz points out, there are better ways to write this anyway.

Comment: Anyone want to comment on *why* we need brackets around the if-expression (other than "because it compiles")?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge this is just speculation, but it may be that they wanted to avoid programmer confusion as to how an expression like `1 + if (b) 2 else 3 + 4` would associate. Is it `1 + (if (b) 2 else 3) + 4` or `1 + (if (b) 2 else 3 + 4)`? Certainly you could have a grammar which resolves this ambiguity (Haskell does), but that doesn't mean people wouldn't make mistakes because they assumed a different behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you are not using `Option[T]` idiomatically, try this:

```
"select * from xx" + order.map(" order by " + _).getOrElse("")
```

or with different syntax:

```
"select * from xx" + (order map {" order by " + _} getOrElse "")
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
"select * from xx" + order match {
  case Some(o) => " order by " + o
  case None => ""
}
```

Have a look at [`scala.Option` Cheat Sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). But if you really want to go the ugly way of `if`s (missing parentheses around `if`):

```
"select * from xx" + (if(order.isDefined) {" order by " + order.get} else {""})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tomasz, I just found it on google... And yes, I'm trying to learn the most idiomatic way to work with Scala...

Answer (score 0):

...or, if you really want to impress your friends:

```
order.foldLeft ("") ((_,b)=>"order by  " + b)
```

(I would still recommend Tomasz's answer, but I think this one is not included in the scala.Option cheat sheet, so i thought I'd mention it)

Comment: If you're gonna fold, why not use the prefix as the initial value, and do the whole thing in one go?  `val sql = order.foldLeft("select * from xx")((_,b)=>" order by " + b) `

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle you're right, that's a way to do it... I was imagining this to be part of a larger dynamically constructed query where you have a function that builds only the "order by" part, another one that builds the "where" clauses and you put them all together at the end